# RTMFP connections

Tags: flash, rtmfp

Excuse me, I would like to clarify this with you. The ingredients to make a RTMFP connection possible are... you require a Cirrus developer key, a Flash Media Server or FMS hosting, a web server and Flash player 10 or higher. Finally will you need to edit your API's in Actionscript or Actionscript 3. Is this correct or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Your client needs Flash Player 10.1 or higher.  If you have a Cirrus key and connect to Cirrus, then you do not need a web server for a simple peer to peer connection.

Your clients will also need an ISP connection and firewall settings that unblock UDP ports.  Most popular US ISPs do this.  If you are not sure about a connection, you can diagnose it here:

Connectivity Checker
http://cc.rtmfp.net/

For example of ActionScript API, here is Adobe's video chat sample:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/